# GSM and GPS shield pin conflict

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, shields, gsm, gps

I have an [Arduino GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield) and I plan to purchase an [Adafruit GPS shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1272). The GPS module uses Pin 7 & 8 for Rx and Tx, but the GSM shield uses Pin 7 for Modem Reset.

Will the overlap on pin 7 affect it in any way? If it does cause issues, how can the problem be avoided?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a question you asked a few days ago ([here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/arduino-shield-stacking)). Are you wanting to ask something specific that wasn't covered there?

Comment: Yes, there they suggested me to go for the adafruit GPS shield. But the shied overlaps with Pin 7. I want to know, If I place this shield on the modem reset pin, how it will affect my application.

Comment: You might want to ask on the Adafruit forums.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [PDF for the Adafruit GPS shield](http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ultimate-gps-logger-shield.pdf), pin 7 is indeed hard wired to `Rx` and pin 8 is hard wired to `Tx`.

[image: Adafruit GPS shield PCB]

These can not be changed.

Looking at the [guide for the Arduino GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield) pin 7 is indeed reserved for modem reset:

> Digital pins 2, 3 and 7 are reserved for communication between the
>   Arduino and modem and cannot be used by your sketches. Communication
>   between the moden and Arduino is handled by the Software Serial
>   library on pins 2 and 3. Pin 7 is used for the modem reset.

As this is the case, should you stack the two shields together, without modification, then the *overlap of the `Rx` pin on the GPS shield will cause resets to the modem on the GSM shield*.

So, it seems that your best option is to use the solution provided by RedGrittyBrick, to your previous question [Arduino shield stacking](http://Arduino%20shield%20stacking), the Go-Between Shield

> You hear it all the time in the Arduino community, “will this shield
>   work with my other shield?.” I think we’ve all been disappointed to
>   find that two of our favorite shields compete for control of a digital
>   pin here or a serial pin there. While there are sometimes some clever
>   workarounds from elegant code modifications to aggressive
>   ‘greenwiring,’ Mayhew Labs may have come up with the simplest solution
>   thus far: The Go-Between Shield.

Once you have used the Go-Between shield to reassign the `Rx` pin to something that the GSM shield does not use, (as 2, 3 and 7 are already used, let's say you use pin 6), then in the **File -> Examples -> Adafruit_GPS -> Parsing** sketch, you will need to change the line

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3,2);
```

to

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8,6);
```

instead of

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8,7);
```

which is recommended in the PDF.

I hope that this answers your question(s). Let us know how you get on.

---

#### Addenum

The [schematic of the Arduino GSM shield](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-gsm-shield-schematic.pdf):
[image]

The [schematic of the Adafruit GPS shield](http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ultimate-gps-logger-shield.pdf):
[image: schematic of the Adafruit GPS shield]